# ASP.NET application not finding DLLs in bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am maintaining a website that is entirely written in ASP classic. I'm adding some new integrations using ASP.NET, but having some trouble.

My application runs 100% fine in Visual Studio, but when I publish it I'm getting this error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Int.OAuth'

Source Error:
    Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OAuth.aspx.cs" Inherits="Int.OAuth" %>
```

That line comes from `OAuth.aspx`

Visual Studio puts the bin folder in the folder with the .aspx file correctly, and it contains all the .dlls, but it seems like ASP.NET can't find them. Could this be because my application is not at the site root? I have the app under: `/ADMIN/api/services/int/`.

Things I've tried:

**1. Tried adding the bin folder to the assembly binding.**

I saw many sources online saying that to tell ASP.NET about a folder with DLLs, you add this to your web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="bin/" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I tried doing that, using a relative paths and also an absolute path, and double checked the paths, but that didn't have any effect.

**2. Tried using `CodeFile=` instead of `CodeBehind=`**

Sources online also suggested changing:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="OAuth.aspx.cs" Inherits="RqQb.OAuth" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="OAuth.aspx.cs" Inherits="RqQb.OAuth" %>
```

This was inconvenient because Visual Studio does not upload the `aspx.cs` files when publishing, so I had to do that manually every time I made the change.

It still didn't solve the problem though. The `using` statements in `OAuth.aspx.cs` then began having errors. These were external libraries, and were all in the bin folder, but apparently not being found.

**3. Tried changing the output path to `/bin`**

Well this seemed like it wouldn't change anything, because it was working just fine in Visual Studio on localhost, but it would break when published (and all the DLLs were in the `bin` folder correctly) but I checked anyway and `Build -> Output path` was already correctly set to `bin\`.

**4. Tried restarting visual studio, stopping localhost, cleaning, rebuilding then publishing again.**

Didn't change anything.

---

For that one smart aleck who always asks: my problem is that I'm having an error, so **my question is how do I get rid of this error?**